# Htaccess - Remove extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm adding a **http://www** if it's missing in the URL. If a redirect happends the .html extension gets added for some reason:

> example.com/about > htaccess > http://www.example.com/about.html

Why does the **.html** gets added?
This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'ld like to have the link without the **.html** part like this:

> example.com/about > htaccess > http://www.example.com/about

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w\d\-]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

I suggest you to use `http://www.example.com/whatever` instead of `http://www.example.com/whatever.html` in your `h refs`.

Comment: Sorry, the "about" part is just an example. I'ld need a global solution.